# CREAR ARCHIVO XML A BASE DE UN DATASET

Tags: vb.net, xml, .net, dataset

Quiero crear un archivo xml basado en información extraída de una DataSet

Esto es lo que he hecho hasta el momento
´´´´

```
Private Sub btnXML(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnXML.Click

        Dim outputFileName As String = "C:\Users\Ing Armandro\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\xmlpesadas" 
        Dim connString As String = "string conn"
        Dim sqlQueryString As String = "SELECT * FROM pesadas"
        writeSQLQueryToFileAsXML(connString, sqlQueryString, outputFileName)
        Console.WriteLine("Wrote query results to {0}", outputFileName)
    End Sub
    Shared Sub writeSQLQueryToFileAsXML(ByVal connString As String, ByVal query As String, ByVal filename As String, ByVal ds As DataSet)
        Dim myConn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(query, myConn)
        Dim myDs As New DataSet
        adapter.Fill(myDs)
        Dim myFs As FileStream = Nothing
        myFs = New FileStream("C:\Users\Ing Armandro\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\xmlpesadas" + ".xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
        myDs.WriteXml(myFs)
        myDs.GetXml()
        myFs.Close()
    End Sub
```

Esto es lo que obtengo con el código actual

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <clave_pesada>110</clave_pesada>
    <fechae>2016:07:06T00:00:0005:00</fechae>
    <horae>PT10H32M55S</horae>
    <pesoe>3180</pesoe>
    <producto>00552                                                                                               </producto>
    <procedencia>98                                                                                                  </procedencia>
    <destino>44                                                                                                  </destino>
    <operador>1</operador>
    <unidad>1</unidad>
    <fechas>2016-07-06T00:00:00-05:00</fechas>
    <horas>PT12H12M29S</horas>
    <pesos>6990</pesos>
    <tipo>B         </tipo>
    <estatus>S</estatus>
    <id>59                                                                                                  </id>
    <pesoec>3180 kg   

                                                                                        </pesoec>
    <empresa>1</empresa>
    <nombre xml:space="preserve">                                                                                                                                                                                                        </nombre>
    <folio>96</folio>
    <usuarioe>1</usuarioe>
    <usuarios>2</usuarios>
  </Table>
```

pero necesito esto

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <clave_pesada>110</clave_pesada>
    <fechae>2016-07-06</fechae>
    <horae>10:32:55</horae>
    <pesoe>3180</pesoe>
    <producto>00552</producto>                                                                                             
    <procedencia>98</procedencia>                                                                                               
    <destino>44</destino>                                                                                                 
    <operador>1</operador>
    <unidad>1</unidad>
    <fechas>2016-07-06</fechas>
    <horas>12:12:29</horas>
    <pesos>6990</pesos>
    <tipo>B</tipo>
    <estatus>S</estatus>
    <id>59</id>                                                                                                 
    <pesoec>3180 kg</pesoec>                                                                                    
    <empresa>1</empresa>
    <nombre xml:space="preserve">NULL</nombre>                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    <folio>96</folio>
    <usuarioe>1</usuarioe>
    <usuarios>2</usuarios>
  </Table>
```